# removing block quote from post text - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and I want to remove the block quotes from the post and put just the regular text. (also want to remove any images that are in the text, I just want the regular text)

This code does the OPPOSITE of what I want - takes out the block quotes and posts that. I want it to post the other text and NOT the block quote.

```
<?php
        // get the content
        $block = get_the_content();

        // check and retrieve blockquote
        if(preg_match('~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~', $block, $matches))

        // output blockquote
        echo $matches[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a content filter. Add the following to your functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'rm_quotes_and_images' );
function rm_quotes_and_images($content) 
{
   $content = preg_replace("~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~", "", $content);
   $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+>/i", "", $content);          
   return $content;
}
```

Comment: I've been getting a lot of comments saying that using preg_replace is bad practice and is not optimal

Comment: That depends on your definition of "optimal". If you want to remove block quotes and images permanently you are better off running a one-time database query to remove them. But if you want a filter to remove them when outputting the page then the preg_replace solution I posted above is the elegant way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'block_the_content_filter' );
function block_the_content_filter($content) {

$content = preg_replace("~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~", "", $content);

return $content;

}
```

Comment: that returns nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your code:

```
$content = preg_replace("~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~", "", $content);
$content = strip_tags($content, '<img>'); 

echo $content;
```

The way wali hassan sayed is to add following code to your function.php:

```
        add_filter( 'the_content', 'block_the_content_filter' );
    function block_the_content_filter($content) {

    $content = preg_replace("~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~", "", $content);
$content = strip_tags($content, '<img>'); 

    return $content;

    }
```

This overrides the default "the_content()" function so in you page template you only need to call:

```
the_content();
```